# How to get access to onclose event codes in Javascript onclose function?

Tags: websocket

I have this simple WebSocket problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>WebSocket Test</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var wsUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org/";
    var output;

    function init() {
        output = document.getElementById("output");
        testWebSocket();
    }
    function testWebSocket() {
        websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
        websocket.onopen = function (evt) {
            onOpen(evt)
        };
        websocket.onclose = function (evt) {
            onClose(evt)
        };
        websocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
            onMessage(evt)
        };
        websocket.onerror = function (evt) {
            onError(evt)
        };
    }
    function onOpen(evt) {
        writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
        doSend("WebSocket rocks");
    }
    function onClose(evt) {
        writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
    }
    function onMessage(evt) {
        writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data + '</span>');
        websocket.close();
    }
    function onError(evt) {
        writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
    }
    function doSend(message) {
        writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
        websocket.send(message);
    }
    function writeToScreen(message) {
        var pre = document.createElement("p");
        pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
        pre.innerHTML = message;
        output.appendChild(pre);
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
</script>
 <h2>WebSocket Test</h2> 
<div id="output"></div>

</html>
```

My question is that how can i have access to the web socket close codes ??
as mentioned in this website

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/WebSockets_reference/CloseEvent

```
1001    CLOSE_GOING_AWAY
1000    CLOSE_NORMAL
1005    CLOSE_NO_STATUS
1006    CLOSE_ABNORMAL
```

Right now this is my onclose function

```
function onClose(evt) { writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED"); }
```

I have put up an alert as alert(evt) ,but i am not getting any close code .

Could anybody please help

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
function onClose(event)
{
    alert('Onclose called' + event);
    alert('code is' + event.code);
    alert('reason is ' + event.reason);
    alert('wasClean  is' + event.wasClean);
}
```

Comment: The first alert will just produce a useless `[object Object]`

Comment: Should be `alert('Onclose called' + JSON.stringify(event));`

Comment: No, that should be `JSON.stringify(event, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(event))` because [otherwise many properties will not be displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815172/log-shows-error-object-istrustedtrue-instead-of-actual-error-data).