# Log shows Error object: {"isTrusted":true} instead of actual error data

Tags: javascript, exception

I have an event handler that looks like this:

```
window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {

    SendLogErrorToServer('Error: ' + e.message +
                         'Error object: ' + JSON.stringify(e) +
                         'Script: ' + e.filename +
                         'Line: ' + e.lineno +
                         'Col: ' + e.colno +
                         'Nav: ' + window.navigator.userAgent));

}, false);
```

The problem is that what I receive looks like this:

```
Error: Script error.Error object: {"isTrusted":true} Script: Line: 0 Col: 0 Nav: Mozilla/5.0
```

As you can see, no line number or error message that's useful. What do I need to change to get the line number and error details?

Comment: Which one is your problem : #1) serialization of error to JSON ? Or #2) How to get message and lineno in the first place ? For #1, have you seen [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18391212/6730571)?
 In particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26199752/6730571) and suggestion to use `replacer` parameter for `JSON.stringify()`: `JSON.stringify(e, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e))`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There are two points you need to be aware of in this case. Both points are independent of each other and should be fixed to solve your problem.

### First

The error you're facing is a special type of errors called [`Script Error`](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/05/17/what-is-script-error/)

> “Script error” is what browsers send to the `onerror` callback when an
> error originates from a JavaScript file served from a different origin
> (different domain, port, or protocol). It’s painful because even
> though there’s an error occurring, you don’t know what the error is,
> nor from which code it’s originating.

**This isn’t a JavaScript bug**

> Browsers intentionally hide errors
> originating from script files from different origins for security
> reasons. It’s to avoid a script unintentionally leaking potentially
> sensitive information to an onerror callback that it doesn’t control.
> For this reason, browsers only give `window.onerror` insight into errors
> originating from the same domain. All we know is that an error
> occurred – nothing else!

**To fix this problem:**

To fix and get a normal error object, **Check this [blog post](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/05/17/what-is-script-error/#the-cause-cross-origin-scripts)**

### Second

When you try to stringify any `Error` Object, the result will not be satisfying at all because you will lose almost all data.

**The reason for that**

`JSON.stringify` deals only with enumerable properties but `Error` object stores the contextual data in inenumerable properties.

**To fix this problem**

There are number of solutions but this one could be straight forward

```
JSON.stringify(err, ["message", "arguments", "type", "name"])
```

This picks the properties you want and generate the string for you.

Comment: the *"To fix and get a normal error object"* link is now broken... this is why it's a pain when solutions consist of links on other websites.  Anyway I managed to find a [copy in archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20171109022146/https://blog.sentry.io/2016/05/17/what-is-script-error.html)

Comment: Instead using `JSON.stringify(err);` use `console.error("Error: ", err)`. Note `err` is passed as argument, so whole error would be printed out. This way you will not need to guess field names.

Comment: @hybaken If you only need to log then use `console`. But for example, if you need to save the error to display later (Into a file or over HTTP), you need to serialize it somehow, and `JSON.stringify` is one way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

"Script error" probably means that the issue is with an attempt at executing a script from an external domain.

You don't have information on the line number and error details because it's not on your page.

It's covered pretty extensively in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5913978/7363719).